# Skipping an optional argument in Sass mixin

Tags: sass, mixins

I have this mixin to handle a simple CSS3 linear gradient:

```css
@mixin linear-gradient($from, $to, $dir: bottom, $dir-webkit: top, $ie-filters: false) {
    background-color: $to;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient($dir-webkit, $from, $to);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to $dir, $from, $to);
    @if $ie-filters == true and $old-ie {
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#{ie-hex-str($from)}', endColorstr='#{ie-hex-str($to)}');
    }
}
```

`$dir` is short for 'direction'.

If I need to make `$ie-filters` 'true' and I don't need to change the `$dir` / `$dir-webkit` default values I still need to redeclare them which obviously isn't very DRY and optimal, so I'd have to do this:

```
@include linear-gradient(#7a7a7a, #1a1a1a, bottom, top, true);
```

When I just want to do this:

```
@include linear-gradient(#7a7a7a, #1a1a1a, true);
```

How do I skip over arguments in this way when calling a mixin?

PS if you're wondering about the `$dir-webkit` argument it's for Webkit as it still doesn't handle the new gradient syntax (see: http://generatedcontent.org/post/37949105556/updateyourcss3 -> **New gradient syntax**), the direction needs to be the opposite of the standard syntax.

Comment: Did you try, passing null?

Comment: Just tried that but it doesn't output any value when `null` is used: `@include linear-gradient(#f60, #c00, null, null, true);` compiles to: `background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(, #ff6600, #cc0000); background-image: linear-gradient(to, #ff6600, #cc0000);`

Comment: try this http://bravedick.github.com/mooxins/ mixins. no ie filters, btw.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Starting from SASS 3.1 you can pass named arguments to do that:

```
@include linear-gradient($from: #7a7a7a, $to: #1a1a1a, $ie-filters: true);
```

The rest will be default.

Comment: `$from` and `$to` will never have defaults, but even if they did it still doesn't help when I want to skip an argument like I've described above.

Comment: What? I just showed you how it works, that was exactly what you asked. You want to skip over the 3rd and 4th argument and this is how it's done.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand my answer. This is how you CALL the mixin with your values. You can ommit the two other parameters as long as you pass named arguments.

Comment: Sorry mate, I stupidly misread `@include` for `@mixin` in your code snippet so I thought you were declaring defaults for `$from` and `$to` in the actual mixin. Been working in mixins all day so the brain is a bit frazzled. Anyway all works fine. Cheers.

Comment: Is there any other alternative, eg. like passing null or something?? Thx!

Comment: @AdrianaHernández no. You can specifically code support logic inside your mixin, checking your parameters to be null and setting default values, but I would be careful to do that since it's non standard way to implement default valued parameters so it isn't going to be intuitive from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that it's been 10 years. While I may not be answering the question directly, I hope this can help someone else.

With `"sass": "^1.67.0"`

I attempted a workaround, and it was successful. However, if you don't want to include them during `@include`, you'll need to specify a default `null` value.

```scss
// _mixins.scss
@mixin flex-base(
  $display: flex,
  $direction: null,
  $wrap: null,
  $align: null,
  $justify: null,
  $gap: null
) {
  display: $display;
  flex-direction: if($direction, $direction, null);
  flex-wrap: if($wrap, $wrap, null);
  align-items: if($align, $align, null);
  justify-content: if($justify, $justify, null);
  gap: if($gap, $gap, null);
}

// _sth.scss
.sth {
  @include flex-base($align: center, $justify: center);

  &__else {
    @include flex-base($align: center, $gap: 4rem);

    @media screen and (max-width: 767.98px) {
      @include flex-base($direction: column);
    }
  }
}
```